# Identifying the GeoPoint that trigger an onTap call

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a Google Maps app on Android. I have a number of GeoPoints that I'm displaying by adding them as OverlayItems to an ItemizedOverlay. This works well for displaying them and bringing up a nice box when I click them, however I'm trying to put info in the box it brings up.

Thus, I've extended ItemizedOverlay with my own class, and I'm overriding `onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView)`. At first I thought that this would be very simple, as one of the parameters is the GeoPoint, so I would know exactly which GeoPoint was clicked. However, from what I can tell, the GeoPoint argument there is the GeoPoint for where the user actually touched. Given the range the user can touch and still trigger the `onTap`, that GeoPoint isn't very helpful for knowing precisely which GeoPoint was actually touched.

I'm currently checking the parameter GeoPoint against all my existing GeoPoints and seeing which it's closest to. This seems like a super hacky abstraction inversion. Is there a better way to know what was actually tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView)` you should override the method:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index){
    //you code here
}
```

where `index` will point you to the right `OverlayItem`.

Regards.

Comment: I'm overriding both onTap(int index) and onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView), and using logs, the index one is never called. Is there a way to make that one be called instead?

Comment: Callbacks handling touch events should return `true` if they handled the touch event and it will not be further dispatched. If `false` is returned the touch has not been handled and it will be dispatched to other callbacks or view. So, in your case, just delete one of `onTouch` if you don't need it, or return false in the first one being called.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Just to save others that last bit of research, after indexing into the OverlayItems, getPoint is will actually pull a GeoPoint out of an OverlayItem.